# Не выводит информацию от POST запроса от ACF

Tags: wordpress, acf

Передаю данный код

```
{
    "title":{
        "raw": "Тестирую работу отзыва"
    },

   "acf": {
        "opisanie": "Тестирую работу отзыва"
    },
    
    
   "status": "publish"
}
```

Приходит пустое поле ACF описание. Не могу понять причину. REST API везде включен. Авторизация есть по методу приложения. Статья создается а в поле ничего не заходит

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
    "title":{
        "raw": "Тестирую работу отзыва"
    },
     "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "<p>This is an example page. It&#8217;s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to potential site visitors. It might say something like this: Hi there! I&#8217;m a bike messenger [&hellip;]<\/p>\n",
      "protected": false
    },

   "fields": {
        "opisanie": "some interesting update"
    },
    
    
   "status": "publish"
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]